# clang-format K&R braces style

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

I am using `clang-format` based code formatting in **Visual Studio Code**. I was using this config for the formatting:

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup, IndentWidth: 4, AccessModifierOffset: -4, ColumnLimit: 100}",
```

As I was unable to force the `K&R` braces style, I thought about switching to `BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio`, as VS uses that kind of braces and I saw the `Visual Studio` option somewhere.

The problem is, now when I format the code I get the following error:

```
Formatting failed:
"c:\Users\dabljues\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-0.20.1/bin/../LLVM/bin/clang-format.exe" -style="{ BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio, BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup, IndentWidth: 4, AccessModifierOffset: -4, ColumnLimit: 100}" -fallback-style="LLVM" -sort-includes=1 -assume-filename="c:\Users\dabljues\Dropbox\projects\cpp\test\template\src\main.cpp"
  YAML:1:3: error: Unknown value for BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio
  { BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio, BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup, IndentWidth: 4, AccessModifierOffset: -4, ColumnLimit: 100}
    ^
  Error parsing -style: invalid argument
```

Of course, now I looked at the official docs and they say nothing about this option. The problem still persists, as I want this:

```
if ()
{

}
```

instead of this:

```
if () {

}
```

I thought the `Stroustrup` braces style was like this, but it's not. Not even with functions. So my question would be: Do you guys know how to force `clang-format` to use the first braces style I mentioned?

Comment: I think the first variant is called [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style). Though I personally never managed to make clang format work properly.

Comment: You're right, it works. Well, about `clang-format` - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn`t :(

Comment: Wait, so you want K&R style braces, that aren’t K&R style braces?

Comment: Whoops, I guess I said K&R, but what I wanted were just breaks before all the braces - function, switch, if etc.